# Highlight Duplicate row with googlespreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to highlight the duplicate row for the following table.
The purpose is to highlight the student that is absent in more than 2 days using Google Spreadsheet only. The data already modified and only captures a few of them.

```
        |------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|------------|
        |    Day 1   |   Day 2     |    Day 3    |    Day 4    |   Day 5    |
        |------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|------------|
        |John        |John         |Dandy        |Yuri G       |John        |
        |Apppleton   |Appleton     |Appleton     |Anton Doyle  |Appleton    |
        |Yuri G      |Chris        |John         |Appleton     |Yuri G      |
        |Anton Doyle |Anton Doyle  |Anton Doyle  |Asanka       |Anton Doyle |
        |Boyle       |Boyle        |Yuri G       |Reeta        |Asanka      |
```

This is the expected output

[image: Pict1]

The criteria is, if the student absent for 2 days, the highlight will turn green. If 3 days, it will highlight yellow. If 4 days or more will highlight red.
is this possible using conditional formatting in google spreadsheet?
I have tried `=countif(A:C,"John")>2` for more than 3 days. However the formula highlights all of the column in `A:C` . Kindly expect any recommendation for this. thanks

Comment: Appleton is absent for 5 days, but as per rule all Appleton has to be highlighted as red right. Why it is shown in green for the last two. is your rule correct? or the rule is different for this case?

Comment: You need to click on 'Stop if True' button and provide the following three condition in order
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$100,A2)>3
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$100,A2)>2
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$100,A2)>1

Comment: @Karpak pardon me, Appleton should be red also since it is more than 4 days. i got it wrong

Comment: Did you try the above and Did this suggestion work?

Comment: @Karpak i cant find 'Stop if True' Button with google spreadsheet. is this feature available?

Comment: Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the Google Spreadsheet by default stops if any one criteria meets.

You can [Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XsAO1UPP0xKiJcSuSNAii4md4aUXzBHAWIjuPqYUsvs/edit?usp=sharing) to check the formula.

Click on the cell A2 and enter the below formulas in the given order and select corresponding color. Use 'Add Rule' to add each of these rules.

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$100,A2)>3
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$100,A2)>2
=COUNTIF($A$2:$E$100,A2)>1
```